# PyPy + Cpython extension written with Rust (rust-cpython)

Tags: python, pypy

I was going to try using PyPy. But an extension (.so file) I wrote with rust-cpython can't be loaded when executed with `pypy3`:

```
ImportError: No module named 'pkg.lib'
```

where `lib` is my `lib.so` file.

CPython(3.5) loads it fine. I thought PyPy had support for loading CPython extensions.

If not - what do I need to do to load `.so` file compiled with Rust (`rust-cpython`)?

Answer (score 2):

PyPy has *source* compatibility only with CPython's C extension modules.  You need to recompile the .c sources.  Normally this is done by running `setup.py` with PyPy instead of CPython.